# How can I use hyperlinks in PHP to display data on the page it sends you to?

Tags: php, database, hyperlink

I have this piece of code below. It displays the image and name of all the entries in a table in my database. The name is set up to become a hyperlink.Is it possible to make it so when one specific name is clicked that data for only that specific name will be displayed on the page you are sent to?

So for example if I select the first entry that is displayed back "mealname1" and it takes me to the showrecipe.php page, can I make it so I can display all the data I have for "mealname1" and only "mealname1". I'm really lost, I have scoured the internet and my php books but can't find anything to that is relevant.

If there is no way of doing it is there an obvious solution that I am missing?... I am very much a novice to this... thanks for your help guys.

```
<?php
require("db.php");

$prodcatsql = "SELECT * FROM recipes"; 
$prodcatres = mysql_query($prodcatsql);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($prodcatres);

if($numrows == 0)
{
  echo "<h1>No Products</h1>";
  echo "There are no recipes available right now.";
}

else
{
  echo "<table id='recipetable'>";

  while($prodrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($prodcatres))
  {
    echo "<tr>";
      if(empty($prodrow['image'])){
        echo "<td><img
        src='./images/No_image.png' alt='"
        . $prodrow['mealname'] . "'></td>";
      }
      else {
          echo "<td><img src='./images/".$prodrow['image']
          . "' alt='"
          . $prodrow['mealname'] . "'></td>";
      }

        echo "<td>";
           echo '<a href="showrecipe.php?id='.$prodrow['mealname'].'">'.$prodrow['mealname'].'</a>';


           echo "</td>";
         echo "</tr>";
             }

             echo "</table>";
}


?>
```

Comment: Did you know you can use "WHERE" in a query?

Answer (score 0):

Change the query to

```
SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE mealname='$mealname' LIMIT 1;
```

You can remove "LIMIT 1" if you want but this makes sure you will only get 1 or 0 row back. Don't forget to escape the string.

Comment: Sidenote: You don't need the brackets around `WHERE(mealname='$mealname')`

Comment: I know that but i always use them so it looks better for me at least. Also you can add "AND" it's like "&&" in "if".

Comment: Plus, it might even throw an error. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/where-optimizations.html - Brackets are mostly used for sub-queries.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed a few questions lately where the OP's had brackets like that and didn't work. But once they removed them, it worked. MySQL can be a bit weird at times ;-)

Comment: Did he just used the old mysql functions I mean not mysqli? How much faster would it be with mysqli?

Comment: Slightly faster, but for better results, the OP's table should be properly indexed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74662/discussion-between-kriszdev-and-fred-ii).